# XML Text Formatting for XSL Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I hope my title does justice for the question.  Please consider the following block of XML and sample block of XSL.

```
<root>
<level_one>
My first line of text on level_one
<level_two>
My only line of text on level_two
</level_two>
My second line of text on level_one
</level_one>
</root>
```

---

```
<xsl:template match="level_one">
<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
<br/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="level_two"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="level_two">
<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
<br/>
</xsl:template>
```

As it stands, the output (modified here for reading) when executing the above is

```
My first line of text on level_one
<br/>
My only line of text on level_two
<br/>
```

I'm missing the second line of text on level_one.  So I'm wondering two things.

1. Is the XML valid?  From what I know, the answwer is yes, but am I wrong?
2. How can I modify the XSL in order to get the second line (or even more lines in my case than I've shown)?

Thanks

Comment: I think it is not a good xml-style to place sub-tag between text

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the reason for this problem and for an easy and natural solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the XML valid? From what I know,
>   the answwer is yes, but am I wrong?

Yes your XML is valid. Also, contrary to a comment above, there is nothing wrong with having mixed content (text and elements mixed together) in XML. It all depends on context and how the XML is used. For example, it would be almost impossible to author technical manuals without mixed content. (A good example is reference elements mixed with text in paragraph elements.)

> How can I modify the XSL in order to
>   get the second line (or even more
>   lines in my case than I've shown)?

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but the reason you're not seeing the second line of text is because you're only matching the first line with the first `<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>`.

I'm not sure if this would work on your full set of XML data, but you could replace both `level_one` and `level_two` templates with one template that matches all `text()`:

```
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <br/>
  </xsl:template>
```

This produces the following output:

```
  My first line of text on level_one
  <br/>
  My only line of text on level_two
  <br/>
  My second line of text on level_one
  <br/>
```

You could also narrow the match down by specifying the level_one and level_two parents:

```
  <xsl:template match="level_one/text()|level_two/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <br/>
  </xsl:template>
```

This produces the exact same output, but leaves any other text open for matching in other templates.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it helped a lot!  I was avoiding a general text() template so that I could handle with more control the structure and output.  I did end up using the general text() template, but put a stipulation to check the parent so that it only takes effect where I need it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard XSLT processing model of recursive descent using xsl:apply-templates.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
<br/>
</xsl:template>
```

Using `<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>` is bad news. In XSLT 1.0 it only displays the first text node (as you have discovered). In XSLT 2.0 it displays all the child text nodes, space separated, but this probably isn't what you want because it will output the first and third sentences before the second. (Actually you haven't said exactly what output you want so I'm having to guess.)

Answer (score 1):

Even without a template matching `text()`, you can output the two `text()` node children of the current node (`level_one`) by **replacing**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
```

**In XSLT 1.0 it is very important to know that `<xsl:value-of select="$someNodeSet"/>` produces the string value of only the first node** (in document order) of the `$someNodeSet` node-set.

**On the other side**:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$someNodeSet"/>
```

copies all nodes contained in `$someNodeSet`.

Comment: +1 Great explanation on the usage of value-of vs. copy-of in XSLT 1.0.